# Dynamic import of several names from a module

Tags: python

I am trying to import some symbols from one package into another. I have tried the following, with no luck as both are syntax errors.

```
from signal import SIG*
```

or

```
import _signal
import _re
from signal import [i for i in dir(_signal) if _re.search("^SIG",i)!=None ]
```

Is there a way to do this.

Comment: What makes you think that syntax would work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`importlib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html):

```
import importlib

mod = importlib.import_module('signal')
loc = locals()
for name in dir(mod):
    if name.startswith('SIG'):
        loc[name] = getattr(mod, name)
del mod, loc, importlib
```

Comment: In the documentation for [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) there is the note: `The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.` Is it safe in your case and what would be an alternative?

Comment: @halex: It's safe in this case, but if it makes you feel better you can substitute it with `globals()`; at module scope they are one and the same object anyway. :-)